# RxJS Refactor nested map statement

Tags: angular, refactoring, rxjs, code-cleanup, rxjs5

I have a service which uses `@angular/http` to load data from an API.
I want to create a projection of the retrieved data for my `Components` using this data.

Therefore I wrote the following code:

```
getById(id: string) {
  return this.http
    .get(`https://my-api.io/${id}`)
    .map(response => response.json())
    .map(contracts =>
      contracts.map(contract =>        # <- Nested map
        new Contract(
          contract['id'],
          contract['description']
        )
      )
    );
}
```

In the **6th** line I have a nested `map`-Statement reducing the readability of my code.

**Question**

Can I do better? Is there an operator in RxJS which I can use instead of creating this kind of nesting?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I understand it correctly, there's no way to reduce the complexity here, since the outside `map` is of `Observable` and the inside is of `Array` type. You can consider separate it out to a function for readability though.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I think you are right. What I try is to transform a list into a single element that should return a list again.

Extracting a method is definetly a good idea.

Maybe somebody knows a more elegant way.

Comment: @Gregor Woiwode In this case I think you need convert `contracts` with `concatAll` then you can apply `.map` for each `contract`, and `combineAll` Observable sequence. Note: you need return Observable, from `.map`, in order to use  `combineAll`  - http://jsbin.com/hududiq/edit?js,console

Comment: Hey I really like your approach.
- It removes nesting.
- There is no need to extract logic into another method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose to use [flatMap/selectMany](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/selectmany.md) to flatten your nested array into a new stream of each single array element. In a next step you can then use `RxJS.map()` to do the actual mapping. Finally collect all mapped array elements with `RxJS.toArray()`into a new observable that provides a single array event:

```
const stream = $http('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
 .map(res => res.data)
 .flatMap(posts => posts)
 .map(post => Object.assign({}, post, { status: false }))
 .toArray();
```

See sample here: http://jsbin.com/vigizihiwu/1/edit?js,console

But I would also consider: is doing such limbo really necessary? If you only have one subscriber at all, map the received array there:

```
const stream = $http('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
 .map(res => res.data);

stream.subscribe(res => {
  const posts = res.map(post => Object.assign({}, post, { status: false }));
  console.log(posts);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Marcel. I just tried it today using another sample.
It turns out that I only missed to map the right property of my json returned by my API.

So `flatMap` is definitly the way to go.

And yes you are right I could map the posts inside the subscription.
My goal was just to get rid of nested arrow-functions.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [@Alexander T.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367138/alexander-t). In my opinion he proposed a nice way to get around the nested `map`-Statement: http://jsbin.com/hududiq/1/edit?js,console

Now my code looks like the following:

```
getByAccountId(id: string) {
  return this.http
    .get(`http://my-api.io/${id}`)
    .map(contractsData => contractsData.json())
    .concatAll()
    .map(contract => Observable.of(new Contract(
                                    contract['id'],
                                    contract['description'])))
    .combineAll();
}
```

Comment: Could you also use `concatMap` and do the concatenation and mapping in a single step?

Comment: I did not tried concatMap yet.
FlatMap seems to do the thing I need.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like tremendously complicated way to do a very simple thing.

If you want to avoid nested `map()` at all cost (even though these are two completely different methods) you can use just one `map()` and then `forEach()` on the array of results:

```
new Observable.of(testData)
  .map(contractsData => {
    var objects = [];
    JSON.parse(contractsData).forEach(o => objects.push(new Contract(o['id'], o['description'])));
    return objects;
  })
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

This will return the same result as your code.

See live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/NQgRVSCQGgPvTkPPGz7O (I included also your code to prove the results are identical).

I'd personally use two `map()`s anyway because it's even more simple:

```
new Observable.of(testData)
  .map(contractsData => JSON.parse(contractsData).map(o => new Contract(o['id'], o['description'])))
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Btw, all operators ending with `*all` work with higher order Observables (aka Observables emitting other Observables) and I was surprised your code works because you're passing an ordinary array to `.concatAll()` instead of an Observable. It turned out to be an undocumented feature of `.concatAll()` thanks to [its inner subscriber](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/util/subscribeToResult.ts#L36). [According to the documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatAll) this shouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.
I was also wondering why concatAll was working. *THUMBS_UP*