# Sequential and dependent queries with rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs, angularfire2

I'm trying to make multiple sequential and dependent queries on a Firebase database.
This is how the database look like :

```
books : { book1: { title: 'Book 1', author: 'author1' } }
authors: { author1: { name: 'Author 1' } }
```

I'd like to retrieve all the books, iterate through them, get the related author name, set the value in each book object and return an Observable array containing the book objects.

I tried this way :

```
getBooks(): Observable<Book[]> {
    return this._af.database
        .list('/books')
        .flatMap(e => e)
        .concatMap(e => this.getAuthor(e.author), (a, b) => {
            a.author = b.lastName;
            return a;
        });
}
```

But this returns the first book only.

Comment: Use `mergeMap()` (alias `flatMap()`)

Comment: Can you be more specific?
I tried to use flatMap(), concatMap(), mergeMap(), etc. but, apparently, I don't know how to use them.

Comment: Can you be more specific? ;-) Please edit the question and post the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried and where you failed.

Comment: @untemps One of these answers could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40170157/rxjs-refactor-nested-map-statement/40180701#40180701 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40346728/merge-subarrays-using-observables/40347238#40347238 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250882/subscribing-to-a-nested-observable/40257871#40257871

Comment: @martin That's sound promissing, thank you.

Comment: You need to use forkJoin

Comment: Well, I didn't find what I need (see above).

Answer (score 0):

Given that `list(/books)` returns an array like `[bookObj, bookObj]` you would need to fetch the author information of each book, no need for concatMap unless order preservation of your input books is required for the output.

```
  getBooks(): Observable<Book[]> {
    return this._af.database
      .list('/books')
      .flatMap(booksArr => Rx.Observable.from(booksArr))
      .flatMap(
        book => this.getAuthor(e.author),
        (book,a) => { 
          a.author = book.lastName; 
          return a; 
        }
      );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks but that actually doesn't work since books is an array with no `flatMap` method.

Comment: ahh, if list('/books') returns a vanilla array then you need to convert it to an observable using `flatMap(booksArr => Rx.Observable.from(booksArr))` so all the books are emitted as events on the observable stream.

Answer (score 0):

Being unable to achieve this using operators, I have created an `Observable` via `create()` method and perform the queries before returning a new array :

```
getBooks(): Observable<Book[]> {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
        const res: Book[] = [];
        this._af.database
            .list('/books').subscribe(books => {
            books.map(book => {
                this.getAuthor(book.author).subscribe(author => {
                    res.push(
                        new Book(book.$key, book.title, author.lastName, book.price, book.image)
                    );
                    if (res.length === books.length) {
                        observer.next(res);
                    }
                })
            });
        });
    });
}
```

That's not what I expected but it works.