# RxJS: JSON data with an array, processing each item further in the stream

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, rxjs, reactive

I receive a HTTP response, which contains, if all goes well, a single array, coded as JSON.
I want to get this array, filter out some items, and process the passing items as events.

What I do so far is:

```
    return this._http.get(url)
        .map((res:Response) => res.json())
        .map((data:any) => {
            if (!Array.isArray(data) || data.length == 0) {
                throw new Error("No items returned, URL: " + url);
            }
            let projects = <ProjectModel[]>service.fromJSONarray(data, this._http);
            return Observable.from(projects)
                .filter((project: ProjectModel) => project.parentProject == null)
                .subscribe(project -> ...)
        })
```

However I don't like the nesting. I assume there's a way to do this:

```
    return this._http.get(url)
        .map((res:Response) => res.json())
        .map((data:any) => {
            ...
            let projects = <ProjectModel[]>service.fromJSONarray(data, this._http);
            ???
        })
        .filter((project: ProjectModel) => project.parentProject == null)
        .subscribe(project -> ...)
```

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you're using RxJS 5 there's even easier way with `concatAll()` and its undocumented feature for flattening nested arrays even though `concatAll()` is made to work with Higher-Order Observables.

```
let data = '[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4}]';

Observable.of(data)
    .map(JSON.parse)
    .concatAll() // each object is emitted separately
    .map(p => p) // transform to ProjectModel
    .filter(p => true) // filter whatever you want
    .subscribe(v => console.log(v));
```

If `service.fromJSONarray` returns just a single instance of `ProjectModel` it can be this simple. If you need `service.fromJSONarray` to return an array you'd put it between `map(JSON.parse)` and `concatAll()`. This demo prints to console:

```
{ id: 1 }
{ id: 2 }
{ id: 3 }
{ id: 4 }
```

However, if you were returning an Observable from `service.fromJSONarray` that emits other observables because it needs to do some extra HTTP requests you'd need to use `concatMap()` or `flatMap()` depending on whether you want to keep the same order of items or not:

```
let data = '[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4}]';

function fromJSONarray(arr) {
    return Observable.from(arr)
        .flatMap(p => Observable.of(p));
}

Observable.of(data)
    .map(d => fromJSONarray(JSON.parse(d)))
    .concatAll()
    .map(p => p) // transform to ProjectModel
    .subscribe(v => console.log(v));
```

The result is the same.

Similar questions:

- [Subscribing to a nested Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250882/subscribing-to-a-nested-observable/40257871#40257871)
- [Merge subarrays using Observables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40346728/merge-subarrays-using-observables/40347238#40347238)
- [RxJS Refactor nested map statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40170157/rxjs-refactor-nested-map-statement/40180701#40180701)

Comment: So `concatAll()` is like the opposite of `toArray()`? Neat!

Answer (score 1):

Any time you're mapping to an array of Observables, you should be thinking [`flatMap`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/selectmany.md)!

In your example, that looks like:

```
return this._http.get(url)
    .map((res:Response) => res.json())
    .flatMap((data:any) => {
        if (!Array.isArray(data) || data.length == 0) {
            throw new Error("No items returned, URL: " + url);
        }
        let projects = <ProjectModel[]>service.fromJSONarray(data, this._http);
        return Observable.from(projects);
    })
    .filter((project: ProjectModel) => project.parentProject == null)
    //...etc
```

Or, more simply

```
Observable
  .range(0, 2)
  .flatMap(() => Observable.from([1, 2, 3]))
  .filter((foo) => foo !== 1)
  .subscribe((res) => console.log(res));

// 2
// 2
// 3
// 3
```