# What is the correct way to avoid using a nested observable subscription in a loop?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm using Angular2 and Firebase via Angularfire2 to get some data from a Firebase Realtime Database (basically a large JSON object).

What I have is a poll system. Polls are in a 'Polls' node, poll responses are in a 'Poll-Responses' node. To link these together I use a 'Poll-Response-Links' node.

So basically, to get responses for a poll, I have to get all links and then get the responses from the links.

The below code works, but I feel as though it's terrible practice. Saying this, I have no idea how to do it correctly.

```
this.teamPollsService.getPollLinkList(id).subscribe((linkList) => {
    this.responses = [];
    for (let link of linkList) {
        this.teamPollsService.getResponse(link['$key']).subscribe((response) => {
            this.responses.push(response);
        });
    }
});
```

I'm hoping someone could shed some light on the correct way to do this and the reasons behind it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to do this in RxJS way then you can unpack the list with `concatAll()` and then with `concatMap()` turn each item into whatever you want with `this.teamPollsService`.

```
this.teamPollsService.getPollLinkList(id)
    .concatAll()
    .concatMap(link => this.teamPollsService.getResponse(link['$key']))
    .subscribe(team => console.log(team));
```

(I didn't test this code)

Operator `concatAll()` flattens arrays (see [RxJS: JSON data with an array, processing each item further in the stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41092488/rxjs-json-data-with-an-array-processing-each-item-further-in-the-stream/41096657#41096657) or [Merge subarrays using Observables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40346728/merge-subarrays-using-observables/40347238#40347238)). Then `concatMap()` reemits a value from the internal Observable.

You could also use `mergeMap()` that doesn't wait until the previous Observable completed (doesn't guarantee same order of items).

Comment: Hi Martin. Thanks for the answer. This partially works for me. The problem is it only returns 1 'response' even when 2 or more exist.

Comment: One response where?

Comment: In the subscribe console.log at the end. One poll can have multiple responses which means there are multiple links

Comment: If `getPollLinkList()` emits multiple arrays it makes no difference. Just make sure `getPollLinkList()` doesn't send complete signal after the first emission.

Comment: So maybe I'm confused here, but when I call `getPollLinkList().concatAll().concatMap(link => console.log(link)) return...` it logs just 1/4 objects (the first one). This is correct?

Comment: If I use `map` instead of `concatMap` I receive 4 results (from the `map`) but then when I subscribe I still only get 1 data object out.

Comment: @Peza can you make a jsbin or jsfiddle demo?